# R: Why does fs::dir_copy fail some of the time?

Tags: r, copy

During a process, I need to copy a directory using `fs::dir_copy(currentPath, newPath)`. Some of the time, I get the following error message:

> `Error in link_copy(links, path(new_path[[i]], path_rel(links, path[[i]])),  : 
>     all(is_link(path)) is not TRUE`

This only happens some of the time, not always. What's more, if I replace my directory with a manual copy of itself (i.e. manually copy directory, delete original, rename the copy), then my code will work.

Could someone please explain why this could be happening? Is there a way I can sidestep that error once and for all?

Comment: Could you run :

        links <- dir_ls(path, recurse = TRUE, type = "symlink",all = TRUE);
        links[!is_link(links)]

Comment: @GorkaKobeaga: I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: @ArnaudFeldmann: I will come back to you with that. The thing is, I cannot control when the error message comes up. Rest assured I will run this next time I see it.

Comment: @ArnaudFeldmann I finally managed to recreate the error and I run the code suggested. It turns out that `identical(links, links[!is_link(links)]) == TRUE`. Does this help?

Comment: I don't know if it is of any incremental value, but `links` consist of exe, pdf, docx and jpg files.

Comment: @ArnaudFeldmann: After manually copy-pasting the file and running the same code on the copied file, the variable `links` is of length 0. It looks like copy-pasting the file manually is "breaking" this "symlink" identity, any idea why that would be or how I can sidestep it?

Comment: Thanks for the info. it is very strange as the package appears to be contradictory. It seems to me that is_link is not behaving properly. I'll check later.

Comment: @ArnaudFeldmann hi, do you have any updates on the above?

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer your question but may help you to further analyse what is going on. One of the great things of R is that you can easily inspect source code. Especially in a situation where unusual things appear to happen, looking at the code may be useful.

In your case, we can inspect the source code of `fs::dir_copy` and trace back to which code generates the error message. If you type `fs::dir_copy` (no parenthesis) into the console, R will print the R code of the function (if the function is not primitive). Doing that here will show you that the `fs:dir_copy` function calls the `fs::link_copy`function. Makes sense, as the error message comes from this function.
We can now print this function with `fs::link_copy`
This function generates the error message in this line:

```
stopifnot(all(is_link(path)))
```

From the error message we know that `all(is_link(path))` returns `FALSE`. Next step is to have a look at the `fs::is_link` function. Here we see that the error may come from the call to the `setNames` function, which depends on the `fs::file_info` function: `res <- file_info(path)` 
Here we see that setNames is called with a condition depending on what the `file_info`function returned:

```
setNames(!is.na(res$type) & res$type == "symlink", res$path)
```

This looks unusual as `setNames` takes an object and a character vector as formals. But then, I am not the developer of these functions ;-)
Perhaps there are issues with the file type on your machine and `fs::file_info(path)` returns something unexpected under some conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although I was aware of some of the things you mentioned, seeing them listed out in a structured approach helps a lot! I think my problem stems from the fact that I'm not sure with what I'm dealing with (i.e. what is a "link"), is there any additional info on that? Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce my problem lately.